# I need help with Ubuntu and my Xbox 360

Tags: windows, media, xbox-360

I am trying to integrate my Ubuntu system with my Xbox 360. Does anybody knows an application (like Windows Media Center) for that?

Comment: I don't think such integration is possible.

Answer (score 1):

look for a DLNA or uPNP streaming app. it should recognize the 360. if you are trying to run Ubuntu off a 360, that's an entirely different story.

Comment: is it possible to put Ubuntu on an xbox? will the xbox be able to play games if using xbmcbuntu?